# I tried adding a YouTube video with HTML on my page but it's not working

Tags: video-streaming

```
<video width="300px" 
height="300px" controls>
<source 
src"https://YouTube.be/y8yv4pn
```

o7qc" type="video/mp4>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<video>` tags are for local files on your computer. Also, make sure to format correctly the element like in this website: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp.
If you were to download a video, and use it in your project, it would look like this:

```
<video width="300px" height="300px" controls>
    <source src="./myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If you want to use Youtube videos, the tag is: `<iframe>`. Here is the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp. Here is some sample code:

```
<iframe width="300px" height="300px" src="https://youtube.com/video"></iframe>
```